# Go Stdin Stdout communication

Tags: go, stdout, stdin

I want to execute a go file which I will specify in a yaml config file and send it a Struct in bytes. How could I do this?

I thought that I could use Stdin and Stdout for this

But can’t figure it out
Yaml config:

```
subscribers:
  temp:
    topics:
      - pi/+/temp
    action: ./temp/tempBinary
```

this is my code:

```
client.Subscribe(NewTopic(a), func(c *Client, msg Message) {
            cmd := exec.Command(v.Action)

            // I actually want to send [msg] to it so it can be used there
            cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(msg.Bytes())

            if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                c.Logger.Infof("Error while executing action: %v", err)
            } else {
                c.Logger.Info("Executed command")
            }

            // I want to handle responses from the called binary
            var out bytes.Buffer
            cmd.Stdout = &out
            c.Logger.Infof("Response: %v", out)
        })
```

I can't figure out how exactly I could do this.

Comment: So you are looking for the implementation of Message.Bytes? Any encoding that can represent all messages will do. Check out [the encoding/* packages](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#pkg-subdirectories). Popular choices are encoding/json and encoding/gob.

Comment: On second thought, encoding/gob is only useful if all actions are Go programs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of what you need at https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_StdinPip, https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_StdoutPipe and https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#example_ReadAll

A decent start would be something like:

```
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stdin.Close()
io.WriteString(stdin, msg.String())

b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
c.Logger.Infof("Response %s", stdout)
```

But this solution doesn't even begin to handle edge cases such as pipes being closed early etc.

This video does a good job of talking through stuff like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHZ2CAZE6Gs&feature=youtu.be&list=PL6